# tablecell not getting selected

Tags: iphone

I am facing a problem with the group table view in editing mode... I have one grouped table view with a edit button added to the navigation item . When the table is in non editing mode i can select the table cells and the selection is shown... But when table goes in editing mode ,by pressing the edit button, i cant select the table cells ..

Can anyone point out a solution for this,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

'nuff said